# EF Core - Primary Identity - error "colum does not allow nulls"

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

I am starting with EF core on a SQL Server 2014 and struggling with a use case.

Basically I have a database already created with this table

```
create TABLE audit_logs(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id),
    namespace varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
```

And my entity is

```
public class AuditLog : AbstractEntity
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("namespace")]
        public string Namespace;
}
```

when I save a new entity I have the error "namespace : column does not allow NULL

and from the SQL server profiler I see the query

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [audit_logs]
DEFAULT VALUES;
SELECT [Id]
FROM [audit_logs]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();
```

where

```
INSERT INTO [audit_logs]
DEFAULT VALUES;
```

fails as it cannot work with non null columns.

Would anybody know how to deactivate the DEFAULT VALUES query? or any other idea to be able to create these entities?

Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

solved it, actually it had nothing to do with my NOT NULL.
I was missing accessors to the fields and therefor ef core was doing some voodoo magic

updated to

```
public class AuditLog : AbstractEntity
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("namespace")]
        public string Namespace { get; set; }
}
```